# Add custom Phabricator Application

Tags: javascript, php, phabricator

I am trying to add a custom application to my phabricator. For the moment, I only extended the [PhabricatorApplication class](https://github.com/phacility/phabricator/blob/master/src/applications/base/PhabricatorApplication.php) the simpliest way I could, and dropped my file in the phabricator/src/extensions directory ([as explained here](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabcontrib/article/adding_new_classes/)).

Here is my simple application code :

```
<?php

final class MyApp extends PhabricatorApplication {
  public function getName() {
    return pht('MyApp');
  }
 public function getBaseURI() {
     return '/MyApp/';
      }
    }
?>
```

I can pin my new application, and click on it, but the problem is I cannot find how to link it to another webpage (e.g. myPhabricator.com/MyApp/***MyCustomAppPage***)

I know Phabricator currently uses the [Javalin JS framework](http://www.javelinjs.com), that it is not documented anywhere, and hard to use for novices. How can I simply link my freshly added "MyApp" button in my phabricator to a simple HTML page that would be in my extensions directory for example.

I saw the getRoutes() method of the [PhabricatorApplication class](https://github.com/phacility/phabricator/blob/master/src/applications/base/PhabricatorApplication.php), but did not understand how it worked.

Thank you for your help

[EDIT 1]

I did as you told me in your first answer : I looked at the countdown application (and all the UIExample app) and started doing my own app. I am starting to get the hang of how things work, although I do have one problem I do not understand.

I created a side navigation bar, with all the different subclasses of a parent class I created, which extends AphrontView.
The thing is my controller doesn't seem to work right, when I click on the items from the navigation bar.
From what I understood, a request is supposed to be sent to it, with a certain URIMap variable in it, which would allow me to know which item was clicked in the navigation bar.

But mine appears to always be empty : in my handleRequestMethod from my controller, the first line is `$map = $request->getURIMap()`, but $map is always empty. I have no way to know which item was clicked by the user, in my navigation bar.

First of all, I would like to know if I am doing things the right way.
If so, at what moment is the URIMap from a request supposed to be defined ?

Thank you very much for your help, I hope you will have time to answer my question again.

Answer (score 3):

Routes say what URLs go to what Controllers. So '/myapp/' should pass to some MyAppHomeController.php file. Our code is fairly well organized. You could use a simple application like Countdown as a guide for how to build a Phabricator Application.

```
public function getRoutes() {
  return array(
    '/myapp/' => array(
      '' => 'MyAppHomeController',
  ));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I am sorry for the late response, but I do have been working on this. I edited my question, for more details..